# finding mean value of a single key in a dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, key

so i currently have a list of dictionary and I don't know how to find the mean but only the sum of the key in a dictionary. I would like to find the mean. So far what I have written is the sum, instead of the mean.
Here is my code to produce the sum:

```
animal =[ 
{
        'dog' : 50,
        'cat' : 30,
        'bat' : 22,        
    },
    {
        'dog' : 10,
        'fox' : 14
    },
    {
        'bat' : 30,
        'cat' : 50}]
'''''

    acc = {}
    for cur_dict in animal:
        for key,val in cur_dict.items():
            if key in acc:
                acc[key]+=val   
            else:
                acc[key] = val
    print(acc)
```

''''

Comment: What do u want to find? The mean or the sum? Be more clear

Comment: There are many ways to do. One of them is to maintain another dictionary that count the number of occurences (instead of the summation of values). Very similar to the code that you have written. Then you need a small processing to divide the sum (which you have done) and the counts of each key

Comment: What is your desired output ?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
lst = [ { 'dog' : 50, 'cat' : 30, 'bat' : 22,
}, { 'dog' : 10, 'fox' : 14 }, { 'bat' : 30, 'cat' : 50}]

keys_lst = []

for dictionary in lst:
    for key in dictionary.keys():
        if key not in keys_lst:
            keys_lst.append(key)

elements = 0
total = 0

mean_lst = []

for key in keys_lst:
    total = 0
    elements = 0
    for dictionary in lst:
        try:
            total += dictionary[key]
            elements += 1
        except KeyError:
            pass
    mean_lst.append(round(total/elements,2))

for x in range(len(keys_lst)):
    print(f"{keys_lst[x]} = {mean_lst[x]}")
```

Output:

```
dog = 30.0
cat = 40.0
bat = 26.0
fox = 14.0
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect (see the results of other answers). You should reset `elements` and `total` inside the outer loop to compute the mean for the current key, not the mean for all keys.

Answer (score 0):

Consider pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

animal = [ { 'dog' : 50, 'cat' : 30, 'bat' : 22,}, { 'dog' : 10, 'fox' : 14 }, {'bat' : 30, 'cat' : 50}]

df = pd.DataFrame(animal)
df_mean = df.mean(axis=0)
print(df_mean)
```

output:

```
dog    30.0
cat    40.0
bat    26.0
fox    14.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close to your expected output. I think you want something like this. This code is very explicit, it might be solved your problem.

```
animal =[ 
    {
        'dog' : 50,
        'cat' : 30,
        'bat' : 22,        
    },
    {
        'dog' : 10,
        'fox' : 14
    },
    {
        'bat' : 30,
        'cat' : 50
    }
]

acc = {'dog' : 0, 'cat' : 0, 'bat' : 0, 'fox' : 0}
count = {'dog' : 0, 'cat' : 0, 'bat' : 0, 'fox' : 0}
for cur_dict in animal:
    for key,val in cur_dict.items():
        if key in acc.keys():
            acc[key] += val
            count[key] += 1
        else:
            acc[key] = val
print("The sum: " + str(acc))
for key in acc.keys():
    if key in acc.keys():
        acc[key] = acc[key] / count[key]

print("The mean: " + str(acc))
```

**Output**

```
The sum: {'dog': 60, 'cat': 80, 'bat': 52, 'fox': 14}
The mean: {'dog': 30.0, 'cat': 40.0, 'bat': 26.0, 'fox': 14.0}
```

In the advanced level of programming, it can be solved using the **pandas** library.

```
#Importing the library
import pandas

#Creating the matrix
mat = pandas.DataFrame(animal)

#Finding the mean
mean = mat.mean()
print(mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bit slower than a direct computation, but I suggest you use a two steps method: first, gather the values; second, aggregate them.

```
n_by_animals =[{ 'dog' : 50,
                  'cat' : 30,
                  'bat' : 22,
                }, {
                  'dog' : 10,
                  'fox' : 14
                }, {
                  'bat' : 30,
                  'cat' : 50
                }]
```

You have to merge the dictionaries first:

```
merged = {}
for n_by_animal in n_by_animals:
    for a, n in n_by_animal.items():
        merged.setdefault(a, []).append(n)
```

(See [`setdefault` doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) for information.)

```
print(merged)
# {'bat': [22, 30], 'fox': [14], 'dog': [50, 10], 'cat': [30, 50]}
```

And then compute the mean (or the median, the max, the min, the count, the sum... whatever aggregate value you want):

```
print({a: sum(ns)/len(ns) for a, ns in merged.items()})
# {'bat': 26, 'fox': 14, 'dog': 30, 'cat': 40}
```